# How to Stub on Spy Object’s suspend method?

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, mockito-kotlin

I got the idea how to stub suspend functions of regular mock object and also how to stub regular method of spy object.

However, I did not find a way to stub the suspend function of spy objects.

For e.g:

If I do `whenever(method).thenReturn()` gives me null exception since I pass any() as parameters.I did not find a way to call

```
doReturn().when(suspendFunction())
```

For the suspend methods in spy object.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.